# use existing http client for SOAP call

Tags: java, jax-ws, dropwizard

I've got a working [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/) project, which has several ways of getting data it needs. One of those ways is the JAX-RS client that Dropwizard provides, the [JerseyClient](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/client.html#man-client-jersey). This client is configured so that it suits my needs (uses the proper proxy, timeouts etc...)

Now my project has a new requirement for which I need to do a SOAP call. I've got that functionally working using the following code:

```java
// not the actual structure, edited to make a minimal example
// SERVICE_QNAME and PORT_QNAME are hardcoded strings, config.url comes
// from the configuration
import javax.xml.ws.*;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

Service service = Service.create(SERVICE_QNAME);
service.addPort(PORT_QNAME, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, config.url);
Dispatch dispatch = service.createDispatch(PORT_QNAME, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
dispatch.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, config.url);


Message message = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();
// do stuff to fill the message
response = dispatch.invoke(message);
```

This is all out-of-the-box behaviour, anything happening here is provided either by java (8) or Dropwizard.

This code however uses it's own http connectors, bypassing anything I've set up in my JAX-RS client. I would like to re-use the JerseyClient's http capabilities in the JAX-WS client in a non-copy-paste kinda way.

Is there a way I can set up the Dispatch so that it will use the existing http connectors? Or some other SOAP client to achieve the same?

Comment: My thoughts:1) you are not telling what `client` you are using to make the `SOAP` calls over `HTTP`; 2) `Dropwizard`comes with bundled `Jersey`. It's a `JAX-**R**S` client.For `SOAP` calls there is `JAX-**W**S` standard and implementation.3) `Jersey client` exposes the [underlying HTTP connectors](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4971). I don't see in the JavaDocs a standard interface for getting `HTTP` connection from the configured provider but it should be possible. If you have a HTTP connection than your WS client should be able to use it.

Comment: Agreed with @zloster that this question is not sensible without details about the SOAP client; it is really a question about whether that SOAP client has a way to plug in an ApacheHttpClient dependency.

Comment: I agree with you both: I *am* trying to plug in the jax-rs client's http connection into the jax-ws client. As to what jax-ws client I'm using: the entirety of my code handling that is in the question. So whatever java 1.8 or dropwizard packs.

Comment: OK, here is the answer: it is very possible and it is working: https://github.com/boekhold/jaxws-jersey-client-api I've found it thanks to [this message on the Jetty's mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-users/msg05591.html) The code works with the latest 2.29.1 Jersey (and adding `HK2` as explicit dependency). Checked with [this simple ISBN validation service](http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/isbnservice.wso?wsdl).

Comment: If a licensing is a concern, check [this example from the repository of `Metro JAX-WS`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/tree/master/jaxws-ri/extras/transports/async-client-transport/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/async_client_transport). I'm not sure which async HTTP they are using but it is demostrating how to add HTTP library and use it to implement transport for JAX-WS client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @zloster for the research and suggestions. I decided to take another route however.

I found the SAAJ standard and am using that now. I created a subclass for `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection` and based that on `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection`. That part wasn't all that hard and leaves me with a relatively small class.

Now in my code I replaced the code above with something along these lines:

```java
SOAPConnection soapConnection = new JerseySOAPConnection(httpClient, soapProtocol);
Message message = MessageFactory.newInstance(soapProtocol).createMessage();
// do stuff to fill the message
response = soapConnection.call(message, config.url);
```

Due to my implementation not all that portable, but I don't really need it to be. Again, thanks for those who helped me get to this!